# How to send an existing object containing headers, statuscode and body?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a function that returns an object containing everything needed to reply to a request.

```
const response = {
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml'},
  statusCode: 200,
  body: "<svg ...>"
};

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  ?
})
```

How can I reply with the `response` object directly?

Comment: I think you have to use res.set({ ... }) to set headers and use res.send to set body. You can also use res.sendFile( ... ) to return an image

Comment: I see, there is no direct way to do it. Thanks. I think that came from AWS Lamda (with exports.handler), not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no direct way to do that.
but you can write your own function that will do this for you. Like

```
const yourResponse = {
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml'},
  statusCode: 200,
  body: "<svg ...>"
};

const sendResponse = function(req, res, yourResponse){
  res.set(yourResponse.headers);
  res.status(yourResponse.statusCode).send(yourResponse.body);
}

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  sendResponse(req, res, response);
})
```